# how to integrate google map?

Tags: google-maps

i had implemented google map API with phoogle.php. Its working fine. But i cant able to view multiple places.

Example: all country,all beaches

Answer (score 0):

Not completely clear from your question what it is that you are trying to do here.

I had a look at the [Phoogle](http://www.systemsevendesigns.com/files/phoogleDoc.pdf) documentation and it seems like the framework it provides is pretty limiting.

It exposes some methods for setting a key, displaying a map, configuring a few basic UI characteristics and setting the zoom level.  It seems like you can also add addresses to be geocoded to lat,lng and then added to the map as markers.

It won't geocode anything as generic as "all countries" or "all beaches".

I can only suggest (and I am guess wildly here) that you might want to populate a list of countries and then geocode (*addAddress*) just the country names to place markers on the map for each of those countries.

I can't imagine you wanted to place a marker on "all beaches", but you might want a list of beaches ("palm beach, sydney, australia" for [example](http://maps.google.com.au/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=palm+beach,sydney,australia&sll=-25.335448,135.745076&sspn=45.274786,79.013672&ie=UTF8&ll=-33.602825,151.321392&spn=0.041606,0.077162&t=h&z=14&iwloc=A)) and similary geocode those names and mark then on the map.

If you would like to read more about what the Google Maps API is capable of, I suggest you have a look at the [API Reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html).

If there is something more specific that you wanted to do, please update the question and we would be happy to help.